# Fingers as $n-1$ multiplication

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the following question I can explain why this multiplication works for $9,4,6,8$ and $2$ but for all other numbers I am stuck. Also, the question can be extended to other base multiplication.

So your fingers can provide an $(n-1)$ multiplication table in base $n$, $2\leq n < 10$ as follows: To multiply $(n-1)$ by $k$ by base $n$, lower the $k^{th}$ finger from the left while holding up $n$ fingers. Your answer is $(ab)_{n}$  or $(b)_{n}$ if $a=0$, where $ab$ is a string, a is the numbers of fingers to the left of the finger you lowered, and $b$ is the number of fingers to the right. Explain why this works $without$ listing all the possible cases.

Any hints or explanation through some cases so I can get a better understanding of what is going on as the last two sentences in the problem are throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$(n-1)k=nk-k=n(k-1)+(n-k)$$

As you lower the $k$th finger, you have
$(k-1)$ fingers on the left and $(n-k)$ fingers on the right.

Edit:

Suppose $n=7$,  you move to a planet with inhabitant with $7$ fingers. $n-1=6$, you want to do multiplication table $6$. Suppose you want to figure out what is $6 \times 5$ in base $7$.

$$(7-1) \times 5 = 7 \times 5-5=7(5-1)+(7-5)=7 \times 4 + 2$$

The answer is $42_7$

As you lower your $5$th finger, you see $4$ fingers on your left, and $2$ more fingers on your right. Hey, you immediately figure out the solution, you just have to read off what you see, which is $42_7$.

Hence, the key to solve this problem is to figure out how many fingers are on the left, and on the right as you lower your finger.

Comment: Could you give a specific example so I can try to understand the question slightly better. thanks

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Thanks so much it made it much clearer now I can actually understand the notion you put above it.